# Creating a new Eclipse Che project from a Maven Archetype

Tags: maven, eclipse-che

In Eclipse Che (6.15), I wanted to create a new Maven Project.  From the Workspace menu, I selected `Create Project` and then a type of `Maven`.  I am then shown a dialog where I can select from a set of Archetypes.  The image of what I see is shown next.

[image]

If we the pull-down the Archetype list, I am shown:

[image]

and now the question ... Is there a way to get a larger list of arcehtypes to choose from?  This is obviously only a small subset of possible archetypes.